# Creating Recurring Record Type Opportunity using soap API

Tags: soap-api, opportunity, npsp

I'm attempting to create an Opportunity object via the php soap API. I can create a Single Donation just fine.

The problem stems from the Recurring Gift you must create to attach it to the Opportunity with a Record Type of Recurring. I can create the Recurring Gift fine, attach it to the Contact fine, but when attaching it to the Opportunity, I get the validation error,

> The Pledge/Recurring Gift with ID: XXXXXXX does not have a Recurrence Schedule set. From the Pledge/Recurring Gift, click Save under the Recurring Information section.

The same thing happens when trying to create it manually within Salesforce. The field it's referring to is this one:

[image: field]

Until I literally click "Save Schedule", it can't be attached to the Opportunity. There *has* to be a workaround or a way I can do this programmatically?

Comment: is this a non profit package for SF or your custom recurring code for the opportunity?

Comment: What is "Recurrence Schedule set"? Looks like you will have to create a "Recurrence Schedule set" record, link it to Pledge/Recurring Gift record and then save.

Comment: @Eric, the non profit package

Comment: I'm not finding a "Recurrence Schedule" in my WSDL, I have no idea what it is. I'm very fresh to SF, is there a way to hunt down where that record would exist? @Salesforcesmarty

Comment: Do you see any methods to create a schedule? Or post the method definition for Recurring gift creation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [SoqlXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/), I was able to compare 2 Recurring Gifts. One that I had pressed "Save Schedule" on, the other was fresh from the API call.

Comparing them, there were a few fields, `cv__RecurrenceInterval__c`, `cv__RecurrenceType__c`, `cv__Next_Payment_Date__c`, `cv__Paid_Through__C`, that were different. By adding the appropriate values, it integrated fine with the Opportunity! I could not have found the differences as quickly without SoqlXplorer. Saved my butt big time!